React/Typscript async await operation
I'm trying to read the state of 3 LEDs from a server. When the page opens, I want to update the state of the LEDs based on on/off. I'm using async/await and useState/useEffect. I can receive the json from the server fine, but when I try to get the state of a particular LED, I get '...' expected. In the return statement of the function ToggleLed() I explain what I want to do. I can get the data but I need the state of the led so I can set the color of that led on the page correctly.
I'm providing the code as well as a screen shot of the page in debug mode.
No matter what I've done, I cannot get the false (expected) state of the LED into a form where I can do this "redLedOn button color dark red : button color very light red".
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function ToggleLED() {

  const getLed = async () => {
    try {
      const webResult = await fetch("/api/get-led");
      const myText = await webResult.text();
      const ledjson = JSON.parse(myText);

      // Log the text and JSON
      console.log(myText);
      console.log(ledjson);

      // Return the JSON
      return ledjson;

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const processLedData = async () => {
    const result = await getLed();
    setRedLedOn(result.is_red_led_on);
    
    // Log
    console.log("result.is_red_led_on = " + result.is_red_led_on);
    console.log("redLedOn = " + redLedOn);
  }

  const [redLedOn, setRedLedOn] = useState(processLedData);

  useEffect(() => {
    processLedData();
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="hdrcenter">Click To Toggle</h1>

      {/* Red button */}
      <div className="container py-4 px-20 mx-0 min-w-full flex flex-col items-center">
        <button className="btnred btn-circle btn-lg h-28 w-28
        text-black
          transition-colors 
          duration-150 
        hover:bg-red-400 
        hover:text-black"
        
        //{*************************************************************
          // Need state of led here to toggle background color such as
          // redLedOn ?  'bg-red-400' : 'bg-red-10'
        // } // But I get little squiggley here saying '...' expected TS(1005)
        
        >
          Led Off
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


Debug Screen

It's not clear to me what the screen shot is meant to illustrate, or how the question is related to async/await.  As for the code shown, is that the code which produces the "little squiggley" error?  It looks like the comment itself is very malformed, that's not how one would write comments in JSX.  Is that the problem?  What happens if you remove that attempt at comments and add your attempt to use the state value?

Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

This also doesn't make sense, or at least doesn't do what you probably expect: useState(processLedData) - This is initializing the state to a function, not a value.  Even invoking the function would initialize state to a Promise, not a value.  Supply a default value for the state here instead, or no value (which would be undefined).

The screen shot was just to show the output from the server along with debug, just thought it would add to the  question. useState(processLedData) is to fetch the initial value of the led state so it can be displayed. I want the led state on the server to display on render of this page and so I thought that was one way to do it. I'll try what you suggest.

Instead of setting intial value of setRedLedOn to processLedData set it to false
 const [redLedOn, setRedLedOn] = useState(false);

Why?
As processLedData returns nothing in code but it sets a value to redLedOn
when you use useEffect te data will be fetched and set to the actual value automatically
